# Spring integration sftp new version upgrade issues

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp, apache-sshd

**Error Log**

> [sshd-SshClient[thread-4] WARN  o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier - Server at server presented unverified RSA key: SHA256:key
>
> [sshd-SshClient[thread-3] WARN  o.a.s.c.s.ClientSessionImpl - exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[server])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection >reset
> [sshd-SshClient[thread-1] INFO  o.a.s.c.s.ClientSessionImpl - Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[server]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600609/600000 ms.

For first line log known host file was accepted earlier but now it was not able to because of apache-sshd implemenation by spring integration team and for second line, when I checked came to know we can set heatbeat but in spring integration not getting how to pass

Comment: knownHostsResource::An org.springframework.core.io.Resource that used for a host key repository. The content of the resource has to be the same format as OpenSSH known_hosts file and is required and must be pre-populated if allowUnknownKeys is false. this property not able to set

Comment: I think fixed it by creating SshClient externalClient = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient(); and set those keys needed and passed to the DefaultSftpSessionFactory

Comment: Sounds good! Would you mind adding a full answer to your question? So, that would be helpful for the community to not ask same question again. And with that we might realize what else can be fixed on Spring Integration side.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I have added the answer

Answer (score 1):

@Configuration
public class SftpConfiguration {

```
@Value("${sftp.known-hosts}")
private Resource knownHosts;
@Value("${sftp.host}")
private String host;
@Value("${sftp.port}")
private int port;
@Value("${sftp.username}")
private String user;
@Value("${sftp.privatekey}")
private Resource privateKey;
@Value("${sftp.privateKeyPassphrase}")
private String privateKeyPassphrase;

@Bean(name = "sftpSessionFactory")
public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() throws IOException {
    SshClient externalClient = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
    // serverKeyverifier will help to set the knowHosts
    ResourceKnownHostsServerKeyVerifier serverKeyVerifier = null;
    if (this.knownHosts != null) {
        serverKeyVerifier = new ResourceKnownHostsServerKeyVerifier(knownHosts);
    }
    externalClient.setServerKeyVerifier(serverKeyVerifier);
    if (this.privateKey != null) {
        IoResource<Resource> privateKeyResource = new AbstractIoResource<>(Resource.class, this.privateKey) {
            public InputStream openInputStream() throws IOException {
                return (this.getResourceValue()).getInputStream();
            }
        };

        try {
            Collection<KeyPair> keys = SecurityUtils.getKeyPairResourceParser().
                    loadKeyPairs(null, privateKeyResource,FilePasswordProvider.of(this.privateKeyPassphrase));
            externalClient.setKeyIdentityProvider(KeyIdentityProvider.wrapKeyPairs(keys));
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
            throw new IOException("Cannot load private key: " + this.privateKey.getFilename(), ex);
        }
    }
    CoreModuleProperties.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL.set(externalClient, Duration.ofSeconds(10));

    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(externalClient, false);
    sftpSessionFactory.setHost(host);
    sftpSessionFactory.setPort(port);
    sftpSessionFactory.setUser(user);

    return sftpSessionFactory;
}
```

}

Comment: CoreModuleProperties.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL is helping use to set the heart beat property

Comment: I see. I wonder if we can expose on the `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` something like `setSshClientProperties(Map<String, Object> properties)` which would help to keep it transparent.

Comment: yeah it will be gddd to pass for heart beat but for knownHosts there should be a way to pass those too.